# pre-trained tensorflow neural network model

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

How to get extract weights from the pre-trained tensor flow? I am using tensorflow for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have trained a model or restored a previously trained model, you can get any tensor using the `get_tensor_by_name()` method associated with the graph object.

```
weights = graph.get_tensor_by_name("NameScope/name:0")
```

If you weights are defined in your graph like so:

```
with tf.name_scope("Variables"):
    initial = tf.random_normal(dtype=tf.float32, shape=shape)
    l1_weights = tf.Variable(initial, name="weights")
```

Then they can be accessed after training using

```
trained_weights = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Variables/weights:0")
```

Information about saving and restoring your trained models can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model)

and details on `get_tensor_by_name()` can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_tensor_by_name).